# Async Fetch then Close Window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use an asynchronous function to perform a POST request. Once this request has been sent, I wish to close the current window. Below is the code I am using.

```
async function postData() {
    const response = await fetch(destinationUrl, fetchOptions);
    return response.json();
}

postData().then(window.close());
```

The parts work individually, but when combined, the request doesn't seem to be sent before the window closes.

How can I make sure the request is sent before closing the window?

I would like to avoid the use of a timeout if possible.

Comment: You are assigning what window.close returns to the then.... The code you wrote is basically. `var xxx = window.close(); postData().then(xxx);` Too lazy to find the 100s of dupes.

Comment: Take the parens off of window.close

Comment: I would be surprised this code will work after you make the change because the close will not be triggered from the user action.

Comment: @epascarello could you please elaborate? I suppose I would not want user interaction to close this window. The window is opened by another window and is only necessary to make the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a callback to `.then`:

```
async function postData() {
    const response = await fetch(destinationUrl, fetchOptions);
    return response.json();
}

postData().then(() => window.close());
// or more concise:
postData().then(window.close);
```